# Neither hover nor animation working in CSS3

Tags: html, css

Using HTML5 and CSS3, I'm trying to create a div container that, when you hover the mouse over it, slides out and reveals more text. It's definitely not good, efficient code yet, I'm just trying to get the basics to work for a later project. Nothing is happening when I hover the mouse over the div. I tried commenting out the animation part and seeing if just the hover would work, and it doesn't. I tried commenting everything out and writing a very simple animation that required no user interaction, and that didn't work either. I tried running all my code through Dirty Markup and it couldn't find any issues. Because the code is so small, I haven't created a separate style sheet, everything is in the HTML file, and there is no JavaScript element.

I'm stuck. I have no idea why neither hover nor animation are working.

I have written the code in VSCode and have been previewing the file in Mozilla Firefox.

```css
#divHover {
  width: 30px;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  float: left;
}

div ul {
  display: none;
}

div.hoverButton:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  animation-name: listOut;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-name: listOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: listOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

div.hoverButton:hover>p {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverButton" id="divHover">
  <p>D<br>i<br>d<br><br>y<br>o<br>u<br><br>k<br>n<br>o<br>w<br>?<br>
    <ul>
      <li>Only 10% of people who look at a webpage are actually looking for information. Most people are just looking for some form of entertainment</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: [You don't need all those vendor prefixes for CSS animation](https://caniuse.com/css-animation)

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a more real-world example. Good solutions depend on seeing the picture more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things that need to be addressed:

1. You need to set a `position` value for the `left` and `top` properties to work
2. `ul` items should not be children of `p` elements
3. You don't need `float` for the main element

Overall, this seems like an odd choice for an animation. Do you want the box to grow and not move to the right?

```css
#divHover {
  width: 30px;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  position: relative;
}

div ul {
  display: none;
}

#divHover:hover {
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 3s ease;
  animation-name: listOut;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-name: listOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: listOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* change to ul */
#divHover:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes listOut {
  from {
    left: 0px;
  }
  to {
    left: 270px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverButton" id="divHover">
  <p>D<br>i<br>d<br><br>y<br>o<br>u<br><br>k<br>n<br>o<br>w<br>?<br>
   </p>
   <ul>
      <li>Only 10% of people who look at a webpage are actually looking for information. Most people are just looking for some form of entertainment</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

Here's a better solution (no need for `keyframes`):

```css
#divHover {
  width: 30px;
  height: 260px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

div ul {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#divHover:hover {
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}


/* change to ul */

#divHover:hover ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverButton" id="divHover">
  <p>D<br>i<br>d<br><br>y<br>o<br>u<br><br>k<br>n<br>o<br>w<br>?<br>
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Only 10% of people who look at a webpage are actually looking for information. Most people are just looking for some form of entertainment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: At this stage, I am happy for it to do anything, growing or moving to the right are both fine. I will need the main element to float at some point, because if I can get this to work, it will be to the left of a main body of text. I'll try setting a position, though, and I'll remove the p tag.

Comment: Ah..you don't need `float` in the future. A better approach would be to use `flex` or `grid`. I can update this example.

Comment: @Mimsy32 added another example

Comment: That's OK, I'll wait for flex and grid to come up in my course, should be pretty soon. I didn't know I needed to set the position. It's started to work now. I'll remember that in future. Thanks!